# Distinguishing house from home

Tags: word-comparison

The common word [*domus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=domus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) can mean both "house" and "home".
How can I make a distinction between a house and a home in Latin?
For example, I might buy a house but it doesn't feel like a home yet, or I might have a home despite having no house or apartment to live in.
You can replace "house" with any physical place where people live, like an apartment; my goal is to find a way to distinguish a place built for the purpose of living (a house) and a place where I belong and feel safe (a home).

Does the Latin literature perhaps have this distinction somewhere?
The closest thing that came to mind is the saying *ubi cor ibi patria*, but it doesn't really help disambiguating between houses and homes.
What I would really like is a pair of words which could be used for "house" and "home".
It seems that *casa* (and probably others as well) could be used to mean "house but not home" (although it does refer to low-end housing) but I found no word for "home but not house".

Do you have any suggestions for "house" and "home" in Latin?

Comment: Perhaps some distinction could be made with habito vs versor?

Comment: @Nickimite Making the distinction with verbs never crossed my mind, but that sounds like a good idea. Especially if those two are an attested contrasting pair in that sense, that would be great.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: In English "at home" has a feeling of comfort; security; peace-of-mind. Americans invite guests to "make themselves at home". In Latin "domi" = "at home"; "postquam domi suae lesum hospitio recepit..." = "after welcoming Jesus to his home..." (Glosbe: Uses of domi).

Comment: @tony That is precisely the sense of "home" I am after. Indeed, *domus* can mean this but it can also refer to the physical building. The distinction is hard to make with it, although it's certainly the most important word in this topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A word for “house” is probably the easy part:

- **aedes, -ium, f.** literally means “rooms.” Only fits if your dwelling has more than one room, although, if it has only one, you could call it *aedis*.
- **domicilium** and **habitatio** are pretty generic terms

However, I am partial to **tectum** (roof) in the metonymical sense, which I think emphasises the function of a living place to shelter you from the elements, and no more.

For “home” as the place where you belong and feel safe, I would suggest **lar**. It literally refers to the *lares domestici*, the Roman household gods that belonged to the house and often had a small shrine near the hearth, but metonymically also stands for someone's home. *Lar familiaris* seems to have been used in the sense of “familiar home,” e.g. [Sallust quotes Catilina](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/sall.1.html#20) holding a speech about social inequality (that might as well have been held by a Frenchman in 1789 or a Russian in 1917):

> Etenim quis mortalium, cui virile ingenium est, tolerare potest […] illos binas aut amplius domos continuare, nobis larem familiarem nusquam ullum esse?
> *What mortal with a manly character can bear it* […] *when they are joining two or more houses together, while we have nowhere a familiar hearth?*

So if you wanted to say (for example after moving to a city): “I've found a place to live, but I haven't established a home yet.” – you could say: *Tectum subii, sed etiamnum sine lare familiari sum.*

Comment: Excelent suggestion! I would have thought that the plural *lares* would be more common, but your quote from Sallust gainsays my prejudice.

Comment: Excellent indeed. Spanish uses *hogar*, a hearth, which is exactly the same idea minus gods. The only snag might be if you wanted to say that Rome is a city of half a million *lares*, because that implies (which is absurd) one *lar* per household. It is one of those cases where one needs plurals of plurals...

Comment: As a portugese speaker, we use a lot "LAR" to mean home. I can have a home, even if I dont have house. I, and my wife and kids, can have a home, even if we live over the streets, one street each day. As we still hold together, support each other, rely on each other, we have a quit strong LAR, even without house.

Comment: Just adding, I hope, an interesting "cent" to enforce the "lar" as a good word for what you are looking for.

I believe "Home, sweet home" has become an american saying (just learnt this origin is a song) and I believe people use it exactly to express a place they feel comfortable, at ease, safe and enjoy being at.

In Portuguese, the same would be "Lar, doce lar" which is also used to express the same and as far as I could find it comes directly from the latim "LAR".

Comment: @Figulus To be sure, the dictionaries also list plural uses in this sense. For some reason, in one example Ovid prefers the plural *tecta*, but still the singular *larem*: “nunc avis in ramo tecta laremque parat” (Fasti III 242). Who knew birds had lares too?

Comment: @FEST This Portuguese use is most fascinating. I would have thought *lar* might be a bit too culturally specific to be used in a context where we, well, do not believe in domestic lares, but at least the Portuguese seem not to have thought so. Apparently in Spanish you also *can* say *lar* for *hogar*, but it seems to be a latter-day “learned borrowing” from Latin.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of 2020.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/531/79)

Comment: Your suggestion of lār for 'home' is a welcome surprise to me, and even more fascinating is the fact it's still used for 'hearth' in Galician-Portuguese, esp. metonymically. But I would like to offer corrections as well: 1) *habitatium* should be ***habitātiō;*** cf. the rare *habitāculum*. 2) *tēctō subiī* should be ***tēctum*** and the meaning is "I've walked under a roof, covered myself with a roof", i.e. "entered a house". It describes physical movement/change of location and cannot be used to mean "I've found a place to live". 3) *etiam* requires *-num* or *-dum* to mean "still, yet".

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Thank you, I have corrected these. It is not clear to me why you object to the dative *tecto*; do you agree with [this person](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Publius_Virgilius_Maro/xWNHAQAAMAAJ?pg=PA26) that «[apud Virgilium saltem, verbum subire] accusativo adiuncto significat *intrare*, dativo *prope accedere*»? On what grounds do you think it must be read literally? Caesar wrote, «Germani, exercitatissimi in armis, qui inter annos XIII tectum non subissent» (BG I, 36; they had been in the field fourteen years, not exactly the same thing, but surely Ariovist was not …

Comment: … suggesting they had never sought shelter from rain, I think).

Comment: Yes it's clear that "to enter inside the location" is expressed with the accusative, and "to approach it" with the dative, as that commentary says and as you can see for yourself by consulting L&S.—The grounds for reading it literally is the same as in any language I know - the verb in question expresses physical entrance into a space. *tēctum* means "roof of a house" - the soldiers hadn't entered a house for 13 years, being on a continuous campaign. In English "he hasn't stepped inside a house" can be used in the same way, but "he stepped inside a house" can't mean "He found a place to live"

Comment: *sēdēs, is* f.  abode, residence (see Gaffiot), which could stand for *home*. In «Fabulae Faciles: A First Latin Reader», by Ritchie, 1884, you read *ille matrem et puerum benigne excepit, et eis sedem tutam in finibus suis dedit*

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian that does not seem so clear to me. What are we to make of this example, quoted by L&S: *aut dumis subit, albenti si sensit in aethra librantem nisus aquilam, lepus* ([Sil. 5, 283](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/silius/silius5.shtml))? The rabbit does presumably not just approach the shrubbery.

Comment: I'm unsure how to answer so I'll flip it around. Suppose you as a fluent English & German speaker read the sentence *"I've gone to the house",* which the author claims to mean 'Ich hab eine Wohnung gefunden'. You explain to them that 1) it should be 'gone into the house' because *to* means 'zum, in Richtung Haus gehen' expressing direction, and *in* means 'das Haus betreten'; but most importantly 2) 'das Haus betreten' cannot mean 'einen Wohnungsplatz finden'. Because there's no such custom, ritual or cultural metaphor where you become a permanent occupant of any house that you enter.

Comment: —And that person says: "but what about 'John went to the shop to buy some food while his mother went to the cinema'? Presumably he didn't just approach the shop, while his mother probably didn't just walk in the direction of the cinema and come back." How would you reply?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to refer to home as in a special place, *domus* is the word to use, though there are also figurative options, like *focus*, meaning hearth, or by metonymy, home. I believe similar terms have been mentioned in another answer.

If you want to talk about a house, the word *casa* was used to mean house in Late and Medieval Latin, while in Classical Latin it meant hut, cottage, or cabin. Another answer mentions aedes, which works in Classical Latin.

*Mansio* means a dwelling, according to Lewis and Short, when used with a genitive:

> II. Transf. (post-Aug.), a place of abode, a dwelling, habitation.
> A. In gen.: pecorum mansio, Plin. 18, 23, 53, § 194: aestivae, hibernae, vernae, auctumnales, Pall. 1, 9, 5; 1, 12: mansionem apud eum faciemus, Vulg. Joann. 14, 23: multae mansiones, id. ib. 14, 2.

Mansio also is a night quarters or inn, or, in the context of a journey, a stopping place/station.

*Habitatio* can mean dwelling, but also the rent for a dwelling.

Keep in mind, with *habitatio* and *mansio*, they're derived from the verbs *habitare* and *manere*; they still both retain their meanings as action nouns.