# Translation of specific sentence in Latin

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation

I would like to know how could I say something like *"Make yourself at home, but remember you aren't"* in Latin. It is a quirky thing a Brazilian friend says a lot (I've translated it to English) and I'm figuring out a way to incorporate it into a housewarming gift.

I figured out something like *"Domi te facere, sed memento non es"*, with the second verb in the imperative, but I'm not so sure it works. Maybe it needs an object: *"sed memento domum tuam non est"*? I'm just beginning to learn Latin and would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Edit: In the original (Portuguese): *"Sinta-se em casa, mas lembre-se que não está"*. It is used to extend one's hospitality to a visitor, who should *feel* at home, but remember that in fact it is the host's house and, therefore, certain behaviors should not be displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Latin.SE! Could you also provide the original Portuguese and a bit more context, for a better translation?

Comment: Thank you, @Rafael! I have included the original and a brief explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly do not know an idiomatic Latin equivalent for "make yourself at home" or "feel at home," but I think you could say: *Te habeas quasi domi tuae sis* -- "be disposed as if you were at your own home."

(Now of course *domus* is pretty straightforward for home/house, but I also have to point out my old answer to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/distinguishing-house-from-home/14239#14239), suggesting *lar* for "home," which was particularly popular with Portuguese speakers. So you could also say: *... quasi apud larem tuum sis.*)

For the second part, *memento* is fine, but note that the verb *meminisse* (like verbs of thinking, feeling, perceiving mostly do) takes an accusative + infinitive to express the content.

To sum up, I would suggest:

> Te habeas quasi domi tuae sis, sed memento ibi te vero non esse.