# The feeling of home

Tags: vocabulary, idiom

I believe there is an idiom in English that says:

> It feels like home

Or

> something [about it] felt [somehow] like home

This means when you’re at a place where you feel comfortable and as if it was your own home (if it isn’t).

I would like to know how to express this or convey a similar meaning to it in Latin.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: different but related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/distinguishing-house-from-home